# Sublime Text 3 - can't output javascript to browser

Tags: javascript

I am new to web development. I can't output manipulations to the html file(using google) by the js file. I installed sublime text 3 and the packages JSLint, and JSHint. I created a js file called Insert_Special_Chars.js with the code. Is this code wrong? Or is something wrong with my sublime text settings?

```
var resultString = "<p>Text \u00A9.</p>";

var blk = document.getElementById('result');
blk.innerHTML = resultString;
```

the html file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="Insert_Special_Chars.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's running perfectly on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadasjad/7ekd3hf1/ 
. It seems to be error in your Insert_Special_Char.js which may be preventing this code to run correctly

Comment: Weird, It says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in google error check

Answer (score 0):

I had the `<script>` tag at the top of the HTML document. The Javascript code was executing before the HTML page loaded. I moved it under the `</body>` tag, and it worked.

Comment: Ehm, you're not putting anything after the </body> end tag, are you.